# Why always only the first table is painted?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

The test:

1 - Create a Html file with 3 tables, each one 5x5 and fill each row with multiples of 10 between 1...50.

2 - Create a PHP funtion that raffles a number between the range without repeating.

3 - Change the background color of each table data that is equals to raffled number, each row is a array position. Make 3 raffles.

My HTML code:

```
<head>
  <title>Loteria</title>
  <style>
    /* display centered tables */
    .tables {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-around;
    }

    /* space tables from each other */
    table {
      margin: 4em;
    }

    /* give border and spacing table datas and merge its borders */
    table td {
      border: 1px solid black;
      padding: 1em;
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    /* change td background color */
    .bg {
      background-color: blue;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="tables">
    <!-- First Table -->
    <table id="table1">
      <tr class="row0">
        <td>10</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>40</td>
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row1">
        <td>10</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>40</td>
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row2">
        <td>10</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>40</td>
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row3">
        <td>10</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>40</td>
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row4">
        <td>10</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>40</td>
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <!-- Second Table -->
    <table id="table2">
      <tr class="row0">
        <td>10</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>40</td>
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row1">
        <td>10</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>40</td>
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row2">
        <td>10</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>40</td>
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row3">
        <td>10</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>40</td>
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row4">
        <td>10</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>40</td>
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <!-- Third Table -->
    <table id="table3">
      <tr class="row0">
        <td>10</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>40</td>
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row1">
        <td>10</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>40</td>
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row2">
        <td>10</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>40</td>
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row3">
        <td>10</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>40</td>
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row4">
        <td>10</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>40</td>
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP code:

```
      <?php
  function Lottery()
  {
    // declares a empty array
    $arr = [];

    // raffle a multiple of 10 number between 1...50
    while (true) {
      $num = mt_rand(1, 5) * 10;
      if (!in_array($num, $arr)) {
        array_push($arr, $num);
      }
      if (count($arr) > 4) break;
    }

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
      array_fill_keys($arr, $i);
    }
    // sorts the array, but if it is a raffle, so why i would sort it? 
    // return the array
    //sort($arr);
    return $arr;
  }
  $sorteio1 = Lottery(); // first raffle
  $sorteio2 = Lottery(); // second raffle
  $sorteio3 = Lottery(); // third raffle
  ?>
```

JavaScript code:

```
<!-- So, change background color or call php functions from html is kinda messy, so I used 
javascript to make thins easier -->
  <script>
    // receives the table number and raffle object
    function BluePaint(numTable, sorteio) {
      // selects the table with id od numTable
      if (document.querySelector("#table" + numTable)) {
        for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(sorteio)) {
          // selects its rows
          let row = document.querySelector(".row" + key);
          // select its cols
          let cells = row.getElementsByTagName("td");
          // change cols's class to bg 
          for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            if (cells[i].innerText == value) {
              cells[i].className = "bg";
              break;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    // receives arrays from php
    let sorteio1 = <?php echo '["' . implode('", "', $sorteio1) . '"]' ?>;
    let sorteio2 = <?php echo '["' . implode('", "', $sorteio2) . '"]' ?>;
    let sorteio3 = <?php echo '["' . implode('", "', $sorteio3) . '"]' ?>;

    // call funcions
    //BluePaint(1, sorteio1);
    //BluePaint(2, sorteio2);
    BluePaint(3, sorteio3);
  </script>
```

But only the first table got painted, always, even when I explicitly set the table number. There's a better way to do this or am I just trying to do the impossible?

I tried to put the rows number to 0...14, like table 1 (rows 0...4), table 2 (rows 5...9) and table 3 (rows 11...14) but no success too.

EDIT

I decided to use jQuery and made this:

```
function BluePaint(sorteio, numTable) {
  var arr = $.each(sorteio, function(key, value) {
    return value;
  });
  var $rows = $("#table" + numTable).children("tr");
  var $tds = $rows.find("td");
  var i = 0;
  $.each($tds, function() {
    if ($(this).text() == arr[i]) $(this).toggleClass("bg");
    i++;
  })
}
```

I'm new to jQuery so I don't this logic is right. But nothing is getting painted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a spin, it should loop through all 5 of the keys. as noted by Tajniak your original code was breaking the loop to early. this code avoids nested for loops and instead leverages the built in array.filter function to select the cell. I simulated the php portion with a simple obj for demo sake.

```js
    function BluePaint(numTable, sorteio) {
      const tbl = document.querySelector("#table" + numTable);
      if (tbl != undefined) {
        checkTableNumbers(sorteio, tbl);
      }
    }
    function checkTableNumbers(sorteio, tbl) {
      let cells, cell;
      Object.keys(sorteio).forEach(function (k) {
        cells = Array.prototype.slice.call(tbl.querySelectorAll('.row' + k +'> td'));
        cell = cells.filter(function (c) { return +c.innerText == sorteio[k]; })[0];
        cell && cell.classList.add('bg');
      });
    }

    // receives arrays from php
    BluePaint(2, { 0:10, 1:20, 2:30, 3:40, 4:50});
```

```css
 /* display centered tables */
    .tables {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-around;
    }

    /* space tables from each other */
    table {
      margin: 4em;
    }

    /* give border and spacing table datas and merge its borders */
    table td {
      border: 1px solid black;
      padding: 1em;
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    /* change td background color */
    .bg {
      background-color: blue;
    }
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Loteria</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="tables">
    <!-- First Table -->
    <table id="table1">
      <tr class="row0">
        <td>10</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>40</td>
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row1">
        <td>10</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>40</td>
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row2">
        <td>10</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>40</td>
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row3">
        <td>10</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>40</td>
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row4">
        <td>10</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>40</td>
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <!-- Second Table -->
    <table id="table2">
      <tr class="row0">
        <td>10</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>40</td>
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row1">
        <td>10</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>40</td>
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row2">
        <td>10</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>40</td>
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row3">
        <td>10</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>40</td>
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row4">
        <td>10</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>40</td>
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <!-- Third Table -->
    <table id="table3">
      <tr class="row0">
        <td>10</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>40</td>
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row1">
        <td>10</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>40</td>
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row2">
        <td>10</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>40</td>
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row3">
        <td>10</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>40</td>
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row4">
        <td>10</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>40</td>
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why inside the filter method did you return +c.innerText? Why + c?

Comment: to convert the innerText value from a string to a number so that it could match the value passed from the sorteio object which i had passed as a number

Answer (score 1):

You break `for` loop after first execution.

```
      for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (cells[i].innerText == value) {
          cells[i].className = "bg";
          break;
        }
      }
```

Change to:

```
      for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (cells[i].innerText == value) {
          cells[i].className = "bg";
        }
      }
```

Problem is with reference to your table. You don't have any, except of one in condition:

```
  if (document.querySelector("#table" + numTable)) {
```

Also order of your code is incorrect. You check if rows`key` have inside value assigned to key.

Pseudocode:

```
Iterate over tables (or explicit take only one specified table)
    Iterate over rows
        Iterate over cells
            Check if value in cell exists in your lottery array
```

Comment: Nothing changed at all... But yeah, I forgot of this break. Only the first table is getting painted and I calling the function with table 3. Nothing on console.

Comment: Comment changed. Order of your code is not sufficient. You don't check all cells for all values.

Comment: I decided to use jquery and edited my question, is this right?